# What is the definition of ILac in following diagram and calculations?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, inductor, driver, power-factor-correction

The attached diagram and calculations refer to following application note:

AN2761 Application note
Solution for designing a transition mode PFC preregulator with the L6562A

I don't have any idea about the "ILac" parameter. What is it and how is it obtained?

[image: the diagram]

[image: the calculations]

Comment: Clearly it says *AC inductor current*. What is it that you don't understand about that?

Comment: @andy aka ; the inductor current is the triangular one. What is the definition of obtained 0.59A value?

Comment: It's the AC content of the current passing through the inductor.

Comment: What you mean "the ac content" ? Well we have the rms value to represent the content of triangular current. But i don't know what does " the ac inductor current" mean? Is it the rms value of the sinusoidal equivalent of the triangular current? If so, why it shouldn't be equal to "ILrms"? Please explain more in basic details.

Comment: RMS is the full AC + DC current